# How to setup a VNC server on Windows 10 and secure with SSH?

Tags: ssh, vnc, openssh, ssh-tunnel, tightvnc

I need to use OpenGL on a remote Win 10 computer so can't use RDP.  I also need a secure connection so VNC over SSH looks like a good solution.

So far I've installed and configured OpenSSH and TightVNC servers on the remote Windows computer.  I've confirmed TightVNC server is listening on port 5900.

I then followed [this](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/tunnel-vnc-over-ssh/) guide to configure PuTTy with port tunneling.

I've also set `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in `sshd_config` on the remote computer.

I can successfully connect/login to the remote Windows computer using PuTTy with tunneling setup for port 5900.

But when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1::5900 or localhost:5900 in the TightVNC viewer it fails to connect giving "Connection has been gracefully closed" error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, I was entering the IP I wanted to tunnel to in PuTTy tunnel config not 127.0.0.1.  I don't know why this works, some docs say to use 127.0.0.1 and other say to use the IP of the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting the same error message.

But in my case it was not just a matter of Putty configuration, but also Windows 10 OpenSSH server and TightVNC server configurations.

So I share all of them just in case somebody else is having the same problem:

** Remote Windows 10 **OpenSSH server** configuration (see links below if you wish to change your server port). These are some
directives I changed in the OpenSSH config file (`%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config`):

```
PermitTunnel yes # default: no
AllowTcpForwarding yes # default: no
```

** Remote Windows 10 **TightVNC server** configuration:

"Access control" tab menu entry, "Loopback Connections" section:
Tickbox "Allow loopback connections" yes (default: no)

** Local **Putty** configuration:

Left menu: **Session**
Host name (or IP address) and port: use IP and OpenSSH server port of your remote Windows 10 (in my case, lets say they are 8.8.8.8 / 22).

Left menu: **Connection - SSH - Tunnels**. I added these entries:

> Source port: 5908 (the local port you will use to enter the tunnel)
>
> Destination: 127.0.0.1:5900 (the port your remote TightVNC server is
> listening)

These two ports do not need to be identical. In my case I preferred to use 590**8** source port (just to remember it tunnels to my remote server at 8.8.8.8).

---

With the above configuration, my VNC client can access the server connecting to:

**127.0.0.1:5908**

---

I also read these links regarding OpenSSH server configuration in Windows 10:

Installation: https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2020/05/21/ssh-server-on-windows-10.aspx

Configuration: [How to change ssh port on windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1501402/how-to-change-ssh-port-on-windows-10/1597490#1597490)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Tunneling: http://woshub.com/ssh-tunnel-port-forward-windows/