# How to change ssh port on windows 10?

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm working on aws cloud image which requires an ssh connection to connect. But my service provider has blocked the port 22 so I can't connect to cloud image. So how can I change Ssh configuration to change the port number from 22 to something other?

Comment: I have cmder and git-bash installed on windows.

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays, you can change the SSH port on Windows 10 easily *(as mentioned by others)*.

All you need is in [this Microsoft documentation page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).

Brief look at:

1. Install SSH server;
2. Change port in config file
   `%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config` *(for Windows)*:
   [image]
3. Add new firewall
   rule with PowerShell running following command as Administrator:
   `New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 2204`
   *where* `2204` *your port*;
4. Restart your 'SSH server' windows service;
5. *(optional)* Delete firewall rule for default `22` port.

Comment: I removed the rule for the default port 22 using this: `Get-NetFirewallPortFilter |
    Where-Object { $_.LocalPort -eq 22 } |
    Get-NetFirewallRule` and then `Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "NAME_OF_THE_RULE"`

Comment: Thank you, bro!

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to change the SSH port in a Windows 10/Server 2016/2019 ,you can change the port in the below file

```
%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config
```

Locate the line that starts with `Port` and edit it there.

Answer (score 0):

You say Windows 10 but of course Windows doesn't natively use ssh.  Though you can install bash or some other shell via the Linux Subsystem for Windows.  This, I trust, is what you mean.  Here are some basic instructions for changing the file containing the port information:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-ssh-port-on-linux-or-unix-server/

```
1:  find / -name "sshd_config" 2>/dev/null 
2:  sudo nano /path/to/file  ##  probably /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
3:  ## locate Port 22 (removing any leading #) 
4:  ctrl-o # save the file 
5:  ctrl-x # exit nano
```

Once you have changed it you simply add the port designation to your ssh command when attempting to connect.

ssh username@host:port

(You may need to make firewall changes if there is one in between.  It depends on the specifics of your arrangement.)

Comment: I had install cmder and git-bash shell on windows. Is any of the shell configurations help for changing the port from 22 to some other port.

Comment: The instructions above should be approximately correct for any shell you have installed.  Let me know if you run into any specific issues.

Comment: Can i change it without installing any linux sub-system. Can i do it only with the use of cmder.

Comment: If cmder gives you bash, then you ought to be able to do just the same.  The Subsystem was what I was assuming you were using to get bash.  (It works great if you are having any issues with cmder.)

Comment: Windows 10 does support OpenSSH now, both server and client. It can be activated via Settings App within Windows, google it.

Comment: Good to know, @JimmyFalcon